# Cassandra create table with nested objects

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to insert data in a table which has request body as

```
{
    "a": {
        "hostUrl": "url path"
    },
    "b": {
        "hostUrl": "abc",
        "hostPort": "port num"
    },
    "c": {
        "Username ": "username"
    }
} 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabletest( a map<text,text>, b map<text,text>, c map<text,text>, created_at text PRIMARY KEY, updated_at text, enabled  int);
```

I am able to insert data from cqlsh but not from Mapper(com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper)

Code piece where getting error in saving from impl:

```
Mapper<DtoClassName> mapper = mappingManager.mapper(DtoClassName);
mapper.save(dtoClassName);
```

Error:

> Codec not found for requested operation:[map<varchar,varchar> - at a

(Here a is the first object in the request body).

Answer (score 0):

DTO Class file had issue, thus resolved it by reforming it from Class to Map<String, String> as:

```
@Column(name = "a")
private Map<String, String> a;

@Column(name = "b")
private Map<String, String> b;
```